# How to concat string to an existing array element using lodash

Tags: json, node.js, lodash

I have a json object which has the following form

```
"data": [{
     "firstName": "XYZ",
     "lastName": "Admin",
     "userId": 1,
     "companyLogo":"Logo"
 }, {
     "firstName": "ABC",
     "lastName": "Admin",
     "userId": 1,
     "companyLogo":"Logo1"
 }, {
     "firstName": "EFG",
     "lastName": "Admin",
     "userId": 1,
     "companyLogo":"Logo2"
 }]
```

I want the following output to concat the logo name with its path using lodash in nodejs

```
 "data": [{
     "firstName": "XYZ",
     "lastName": "Admin",
     "userId": 1,
     "companyLogo":"E:/Logo"
 }, {
     "firstName": "ABC",
     "lastName": "Admin",
     "userId": 1,
     "companyLogo":"E:/Logo1"
 }, {
     "firstName": "EFG",
     "lastName": "Admin",
     "userId": 1,
     "companyLogo":"E:/Logo2"
 }]
```

Is there any function existing which supports this type of concatenation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for an external library:

```
var data = [
{
  "firstName": "XYZ",
  "lastName": "Admin",
  "userId": 1,
  "companyLogo":"Logo"
 },
 {
  "firstName": "ABC",
  "lastName": "Admin",
  "userId": 1,
  "companyLogo":"Logo1"
 },
  {
  "firstName": "EFG",
  "lastName": "Admin",
  "userId": 1,
  "companyLogo":"Logo2"
 }
]

var new_data = data.map(function(elem){ elem.companyLogo = "E: /" + elem.companyLogo; return elem });

console.log(new_data);
```